# rsync via ssh from linux to windows sbs 2003 protocol mismatch

Tags: linux, ssh, windows, rsync

I am trying to backup my linux webserver to our local windows sbs 2003 server in the office. I have set up ssh and cwrsync on the windows server and have confirmed that the linux server can reach the windows server via the command:

```
ssh RemoteUser@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

It asks for a password and connects fine. However when I run this command to start the backup:

```
rsync -avz -e ssh home/account/public_html/some/small/directory/ \
    remote_user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/cygdrive/c/backup/destination/directory/
```

I get this error after entering the password:

> protocol version mismatch -- is your shell clean?

and then it dies.

Has anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This error message is explained in [rsync's FAQ](http://samba.anu.edu.au/rsync/FAQ.html#3).

It means that some program is writing something when the ssh connection is established (and it breaks rsync).

Comment: To clarify: by "writing something", that's "producing some output", not "writing to some file somewhere".

Answer (score 0):

In your /etc/ssh/ssh.conf or if you have your own ssh.conf in your home folder (~/.ssh/...) try to change the protocol version from 2 to 1 or whatever protocol is running on your windows machine.
For more details see man ssh and man ssh.conf

Comment: I'm not completely sure a weird setup involving mixed versions of SSH couldn't cause this message, but I highly doubt it. The “protocol version mismatch” in the message is about the rsync protocol, not about the underlying transport (which happens to be ssh here).